# Find query MongoDB using CakePHP

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

The following is the json array I have in a collection called *claims* in MongoDB.

```
 {
  "xmllisting_id": "537f371fb2e380922fff0e2c",
  "pharmacyfiles_id": "537f3402b2e380732aa6032d",
  "claim": {
    "MemberID": "097110330047532601",
    "PatientShare": "0",
  },
  "modified": ISODate("2014-05-23T13:12:17.191Z"),
  "created": ISODate("2014-05-23T13:12:17.192Z")
}
```

I need to find all claims with a specified `MemberID`.I have tried the following in CakePHP without any success.

```
$claims = $claimobj->find(
   'all',
   array(
       'conditions' => array( 
           'claim' => array('MemberID' =>  '097110330047532601') 
       )
   )
);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding "nested" details in MongoDB usually requires ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Otherwise you are actually asking for an object that has "exactly" the key and "only" the key you are specifying to match. Which of course it does not, as there is more information there:

```
$claims = $claimobj->find(
    'all',
     array(
         'conditions' => array(
             'claim.MemberID' => '097110330047532601'
         )
    )
);
```

So the path is "claim.MemberID" and not `'claim' => array('MemberID' => '097110330047532601' )` as you have written.